# Using CoreBluetooth/CBCentralManager.h framework

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I am using CoreBluetooth framework for first time in my Objective-c code.

My iPhone version is iPhone-3GS.

When I run my code, I get output as "The platform or hardware does not support Bluetooth low energy".

I saw 3GS specifications and got to know that it supports v2.1 with A2DP. But what I expected is whether Bluetooth is powered ON or powered OFF.

How can I get Bluetooth status through objective-c code using CoreBluetooth framework?

How to get Bluetooth status through Objective-c ?

Can anyone share a link or tutorial on this?

Comment: Bluetooth low energy doesn't support in iPhone 3gs. The BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) is supported starts from model iPhone4s

Answer (score 4):

CoreBluetooth is the API meant for Bluetooth LE in iOS5+.
It does not support "normal" Bluetooth or any "normal" Bluetooth profiles.
As far as I remember, the first iOS device supporting Bluetooth LE was the iPhone 4S - your 3GS just does not have the correct hardware.
Bluetooth LE is part of Bluetooth 4.0 and meant for reading sensors and alike...
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth_low_energy

You will definitely not make it work using your 3GS, sorry.

Comment: i tried using private framework "BluetoothManager" from GitHub, but didn't get excepted output. I just want the way to get bluetooth status through Objective-c. Any other framework or any link which is useful in this scenario?

Comment: The real problem here is Apple does not want anybody to develop apps doing plain direct Bluetooth - that's why there is no public API on it. Please share a link to your framework, I am curious to see what it is meant to do.

Comment: @Christoph - Well, there is, kind of. If a standard Bluetooth (non-LE) device is MFi-approved, you can communicate with it via the External Accessory framework. For most people, though, LE and Core Bluetooth is the way to go to communicate to the emerging class of generalized wireless accessories.

Comment: @BradLarson - Agreed, that is an option. Even though I would consider the MFi-approved limitation not to be "plain" bluetooth. Still you would not use CoreBluetooth to communicate with those devices, would you?